# Inkscape is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to run Inkscape from command prompt however the error occurs. I have added c:/Program Files/ Inkscape/inkscape.com in the PATH but this not working.

```
Inkscape is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

Comment: `PATH` should contain [**directory** paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Also why are you using slash (`/`) instead of backslash (`\`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this same issue. However my problem was that I didn't add inkscape to the path. Try leaving the `inkscape.com` off your path and just have it as

```
C:\Program Files\Inkscape
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit old question but I faced the similar issue so I would like to share how I approach the issue because using Inkscape's command line might be quite useful for various reasons.

**Option 1**: You might either change the current directory as

```
cd C:\Program Files\Inkscape\
inkscape
```

Example scenario can be converting the `.svg` file to the `.pdf` which is useful for LaTeX import. To use it for exporting to PDF through Inkscape's command line (assuming that your file is already located in `C:\temp\`):

```
inkscape -D -z --file=C:\temp\logo.svg --export-pdf=C:\temp\logo.pdf --export-latex
```

**Option 2 (Cleaner solution)**: Or you might add

```
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\
```

to the PATH environment variable. In Windows see [this link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/). Then you can run inkscape without changing the current directory.

```
cd C:\temp
inkscape -D -z --file=logo.svg --export-pdf=logo.pdf --export-latex
```